# Eclipse C++ Development Environment

Tags: eclipse

I working on a C++ project in Eclipse environment. I have included all the required header files under Includes section, but still eclipse is unable is detect the header files. Is there anything else that I need to do? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you install Eclipse? What OS are you using?

Comment: You do know that you need to install toolchain separately and that it has to be in path, etc. (http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html)